# use Razor to fill dropdown with Linq2Sql data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm experimenting with ASP.NET MVC3 and want to simply populate a dropdown list with data I get from a LINQ2SQL class, like so

controller (I know, Linq doesn't belong in the controller)

```
var allUsers = (from u in _userDataContext.Users
                            select u).ToList();
            ViewBag.allUsers = allUsers.ToList();
            return View();
```

view:

```
<select id="drop_heroes">
        @foreach (var u in ViewBag.allUsers)
        { 
            <option value="@u.pk_userid">@u.email</option>
        }
    </select>

That works fine, but I would like to use Razor @Html.Dropdownlist to create the same dropdown list, but can't find any info to make this work with Linq data.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know, Linq doesn't belong in the controller

Then why are you using it in a controller? Anyway, at least it's fine that you know it.

Here's an example. As always in an ASP.NET MVC application you start by defining a view model which will represent the data that you need in the view. So in your case you need to display a dropdown so you define a list of users and a selected user id:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedUserId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
}
```

then you define a controller action which will populate this view model from your repository and handle it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Users = _userDataContext.Users.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.pk_userid.ToString(),
            Text = x.email
        })
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally you will have a view which will be strongly typed to your view model and use HTML helpers to generate the dropdownlist:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUserId, Model.Users)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Things to notice:

- Usage of view models
- Usage of a strongly typed view
- Usage of strongly typed HTML helpers to generate markup such as form elements and input fields
- Getting rid of weakly typed structures such as ViewBag

If you follow these simple rules you will see how much easier your life as an ASP.NET MVC developer will become.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I'm using linq in the controller like microsoft itself does just to get a quick example running. Is my way of looping a good practice or would you suggest using the more complex and (in my opinion) less designer friendly solution of using the @ Razor syntax?

Comment: @Jorre, your example of looping is very bad practice and should be replaced with a the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper. Not only that your code will become shorter but it will be strongly typed to your view model and it will generate proper names for the dropdownlist so that the default model binder is able to more easily bind the selectde value back in your POST action.